# How to use the results generated by grunt-folder-list in other grunt tasks

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs

Here's a trimmed version of my Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.config.init({

        folder_list: {
            options: {
                files: false
            },
            files: {
                src: (function() {
                    // some logic here that gets the folders to parse
                }()),
                dest: '.tmp/folderlist.json'
            }
        },

        copy: {
            // Makes a backup of all the views files
            backup: {
                files: grunt.folders.backup
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-folder-list');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

    grunt.registerTask('parse_folders', 'Parsing the generated folder list!', function () {

        var folderJSON = grunt.file.readJSON('.tmp/folderlist.json'),
            backupList = [];

        for (var i = 0, total = folderJSON.length; i < total; i++) {

            var dir = folderJSON[i].location;

            // list of folders for the backup task
            backupList[i] = {
                expand: true, flatten: true, filter: 'isFile',
                src: dir + '/*.php',
                dest: dir + '/bak/'
            };
        }

        grunt.folders = {
            backup: backupList
        };

        /* It gives me something like that:
        backupList: [ 
            { 
              expand: true,
              flatten: true,
              filter: 'isFile',
              src: 'Path/To/My/Files/*.php',
              dest: 'Path/To/My/Files/bak/' 
            },
            { 
              expand: true,
              flatten: true,
              filter: 'isFile',
              src: 'Other/Path/To/My/Files/*.php',
              dest: 'Other/Path/To/My/Files/bak/' 
            },
            // etc.
        ]

         */

    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', 'Test', function () {
        console.log(grunt.folders.backup);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', 'Asset Compiler', function () {

        grunt.task.run('folder_list');
        grunt.task.run('parse_folders');
        grunt.task.run('test');
        grunt.task.run('copy:backup');

    });

};
```

In short:

- The "folder_list" task generates a JSON file.
- The "parse_folders" reads the JSON file and generates the array of objects needed for the copy task
- The "test" task shows me in the console that `grunt.folders.backup` contains the right data!.
- The "copy:backup" outputs

  > > TypeError: Cannot read property 'backup' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"grunt.folder" wouldn't be accessible outside the "parse_folders" task and grunt task aren't met to return data.

A good way to share information between task would be to used the grunt.config which is a global key value global space for your grunt set-up and then retrieve the config this way "'<%= backupList %>'".

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.config.init({

    folder_list: {
        options: {
            files: false
        },
        files: {
            src: (function() {
                // some logic here that gets the folders to parse
            }()),
            dest: '.tmp/folderlist.json'
        }
    },

    copy: {
        // Makes a backup of all the views files
        backup: {
            files: '<%= backupList %>'
        }
    }

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-folder-list');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

grunt.registerTask('parse_folders', 'Parsing the generated folder list!', function () {

    var folderJSON = grunt.file.readJSON('.tmp/folderlist.json'),
        backupList = [];

    for (var i = 0, total = folderJSON.length; i < total; i++) {

        var dir = folderJSON[i].location;

        // list of folders for the backup task
        backupList[i] = {
            expand: true, flatten: true, filter: 'isFile',
            src: dir + '/*.php',
            dest: dir + '/bak/'
        };
    }

    grunt.config.set("backupList", backupList);

    /* It gives me something like that:
    backupList: [ 
        { 
          expand: true,
          flatten: true,
          filter: 'isFile',
          src: 'Path/To/My/Files/*.php',
          dest: 'Path/To/My/Files/bak/' 
        },
        { 
          expand: true,
          flatten: true,
          filter: 'isFile',
          src: 'Other/Path/To/My/Files/*.php',
          dest: 'Other/Path/To/My/Files/bak/' 
        },
        // etc.
    ]

     */

});

grunt.registerTask('test', 'Test', function () {
    console.log(grunt.folders.backup);
});

grunt.registerTask('default', 'Asset Compiler', function () {

    grunt.task.run('folder_list');
    grunt.task.run('parse_folders');
    grunt.task.run('test');
    grunt.task.run('copy:backup');

});

};
```

See documentation: http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config